# Boost components can be found but PCL cannot find boost

Tags: windows, visual-c++, boost, cmake, pcl

I have a pipeline downloading Boost repository and building it with boostrap and ./b2 by using link=static. I can find these libraries several time during the build of my component with find_package in CMake and usually the flag Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS set.
I usually get the successful message as:

```
Found Boost: M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.65") found components: serialization system filesystem thread program_options date_time timer chrono regex
```

At the end I want to find it through PCL and I see it unsets Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS but I get the next error after activating Boost_DEBUG:

```
-- Boost_DIR M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0 and Boost_INCLUDE_DIR M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/include/boost-1_76
  -- Lidar SLAM : using Eigen3::Eigen target (version 3.3.7)
  -- Found required Ceres dependency: Eigen version 3.3.7 in M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/share/eigen3/cmake
  -- Found required Ceres dependency: glog
  -- Found Ceres version: 2.1.0 installed in: M:/GitHub/slam/build/install with components: [EigenSparse, SparseLinearAlgebraLibrary, SchurSpecializations, Multithreading]
  -- BOOST_INCLUDEDIR was not set
  -- Eigen found (include: M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/include/eigen3, version: 3.3.7)
  -- Found Boost 1.76.0 at M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0
  --   Requested configuration: QUIET COMPONENTS system;filesystem;date_time;iostreams;serialization
  -- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake)
  -- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_system 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake)
  -- Found boost_system 1.76.0 at M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0
  -- Boost toolset is vc142 (MSVC 19.29.30148.0)
  -- Scanning M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0/libboost_system-variant*.cmake
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0/libboost_system-variant-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_system-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0/libboost_system-variant-vc142-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_system-vc142-mt-x64-1_76.lib
  -- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_filesystem 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake)
  -- Found boost_filesystem 1.76.0 at M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0
  -- Boost toolset is vc142 (MSVC 19.29.30148.0)
  -- Scanning M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant*.cmake
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-vc142-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_76.lib
  -- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_date_time 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake)
  -- Found boost_date_time 1.76.0 at M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.76.0
  -- Boost toolset is vc142 (MSVC 19.29.30148.0)
  -- Scanning M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.76.0/libboost_date_time-variant*.cmake
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.76.0/libboost_date_time-variant-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.76.0/libboost_date_time-variant-vc142-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-x64-1_76.lib
  -- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_iostreams 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake)
  -- Found boost_iostreams 1.76.0 at M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_iostreams-1.76.0
  -- Boost toolset is vc142 (MSVC 19.29.30148.0)
  -- Scanning M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_iostreams-1.76.0/libboost_iostreams-variant*.cmake
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_iostreams-1.76.0/libboost_iostreams-variant-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_iostreams-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_iostreams-1.76.0/libboost_iostreams-variant-vc142-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_iostreams-vc142-mt-x64-1_76.lib
  -- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_serialization 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake)
  -- Found boost_serialization 1.76.0 at M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_serialization-1.76.0
  -- Boost toolset is vc142 (MSVC 19.29.30148.0)
  -- Scanning M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_serialization-1.76.0/libboost_serialization-variant*.cmake
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_serialization-1.76.0/libboost_serialization-variant-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib
  --   Including M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/boost_serialization-1.76.0/libboost_serialization-variant-vc142-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
  --   [ ] libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_76.lib
  -- Could NOT find Boost: missing: system filesystem date_time iostreams serialization (found M:/GitHub/slam/build/install/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version
   "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.65.0"))
  CMake Error at build/install/CMake/PCLConfig.cmake:42 (message):
    common is required but boost was not found
```

Comment: Which PCL version?

Comment: I have the next PCL version: 1.13.0

Comment: Maybe try setting `PCL_BUILD_WITH_BOOST_DYNAMIC_LINKING_WIN32` to OFF explicitly? See also https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/pcl-1.13.0/cmake/pcl_find_boost.cmake